# Reset Mac's python packages back to default

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been mistakenly installing packages to my global python location instead of virtual environments. When I run

```
pip list
```

I see all these packages

```
    Package                                Version 
-------------------------------------- --------
altgraph                               0.10.2  
asn1crypto                             0.24.0  
bdist-mpkg                             0.5.0   
bonjour-py                             0.3     
cffi                                   1.12.2  
cryptography                           2.6.1   
enum34                                 1.1.6   
future                                 0.17.1  
ipaddress                              1.0.22  
macholib                               1.5.1   
matplotlib                             1.3.1   
modulegraph                            0.10.4  
numpy                                  1.8.0rc1
pip                                    19.1.1  
py2app                                 0.7.3   
pycparser                              2.19    
pyobjc-core                            2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Accounts              2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook           2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit        2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC       2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Automator             2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork             2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa                 2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration         2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-CoreData              2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation          2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-CoreText              2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices    2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-EventKit              2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling     2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents              2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit        2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins      2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage        2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping 2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices        2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Message               2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory         2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes       2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-PubSub                2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-QTKit                 2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Quartz                2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver           2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge       2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit             2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement     2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-Social                2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices          2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration   2.5.1   
pyobjc-framework-WebKit                2.5.1   
pyOpenSSL                              19.0.0  
pyparsing                              2.0.1   
python-dateutil                        1.5     
python-pocket-tools                    0.1     
pytz                                   2013.7  
scipy                                  0.13.0b1
setuptools                             41.0.1  
six                                    1.12.0  
wheel                                  0.33.1  
xattr                                  0.6.4
```

I know things like enum34 and other must have been installed by me but I'm not sure about the others. Is there a way for me to revert all my packages back to what was originally installed? Or find out which ones were added by me and which were defaults? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using brew to manage your global python env:

https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python

You should be able to ignore the default python (or pip uninstall all the clutter) and brew install a new global python. Brew manages the symlinks and what not for you.

Once you get that straightened out, direnv/pipenv are great tools for virtualization so you don't accidentally pip install globally again:

https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/Python